# What if I want to execute identical code when false returned or exception thrown?

Tags: java

My current logic is

```java
try {
    Boolean succeeded = process(); /* May throw SpecificException */
    if (succeeded) { /* next step */ }
    else { /* clean up */ }
} catch (SpecificException e) {
   /* clean up */
}
```

The clean up part is identical. Is there a good solution to avoiding repeating code?

Comment: `throw new SpecificException()` in the else block. This looks like bad API design to me.

Comment: Does the `process();` throw this `SpecificException`? You can always throw a `RuntimeException` yourself (but it is not always a good practice).

Comment: Use finally or move the clean up code to a method which will be invoked

Answer (score 3):

If that try-catch block is a full method (i.e. there's no additional logic that should be executed after that block in the same method), you can write:

```
try {
    Boolean succeeded = process();
    if (succeeded) { 
        /* next step */ 
        ... 
        return;
    }
} catch (SpecificException e) {
    // don't throw an exception
}
/* clean up */
```

Comment: If this is in the middle of a function/method, that `return` might be a problem.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes - that's why I wrote `i.e. there's no additional logic that should be executed after that block in the same method`

Comment: Just in case I wasn't the only one who missed your note.

Comment: This can be used even if there is some other logic. Just take the `succeeded` variable out before the `try` statement and set the initial value to `false`. After the `try-catch` block just run cleanup code only `if (!succeeded) { /* clean up */}`

Answer (score 1):

The particular goal can be achieved by factoring out the clean up code in a method named `cleanup()` for example and then calling it from `else` as well as `catch` block

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can throw an `Exception` when it is *not* succeeded, if it makes sense for your code to do so.

```
try {
    Boolean succeeded = process();
    if (succeeded) { 
        //Your code
    }
    else {
        throw new SpecificException(); //or a different custom exception
    }
} catch (SpecificException e) {
  //Clean up
}
```

You can also have the logic of `process()` itself throw a custom `Exception` upward so you do not need an `if-else` block at all.  This would look like this:

```
try {
    //Process throws a custom ProcessFailureException upwards on a failure
    process(); 
    //Your other code
} catch (SpecificException | ProcessFailureException e) {
    //Clean up
}
```

This highly depends if you *want* your code to throw an exception when something horribly wrong happens.